# Proper design pattern for passing flags to an object

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enum-flags

In C I've done this sort of thing

```
enum { USE_COKE = 1,
        USE_PEPSI = 2,
        USE_JUICE = 4,
        USE_WATER = 8 };

 int makeDrink(int flags);

 //...

 int rcode = makeDrink(USE_COKE | USE_JUICE | USE_WATER);
```

I know this is pretty standard, it's also used in `iostream` for instance.  I'm wondering how to translate this design pattern into Java or OOP?  I'm *pretty* sure polymorphism is not the way to go here since it'd be better for my code to have an `if(flag_is_set)` block than rewrite much of the routine.  Is there a utility `Flags` class, or a preferred way to do this using a configuration object, or an `enum`, or a bunch of ints, etc.

Comment: You don't need the flags in Java, simply use an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has enumerations. Here's the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

I would use these over ints etc. It's a type-safe solution, and since enums are objects, you can attach behaviours and avoid `switch` statements.

You can combine these (as above) using an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). From the doc:

> A specialized Set implementation for use with enum types .... This
>   representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time
>   performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a
>   high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit
>   flags."

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Brian Agnew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582061/642706) is correct. Java has a powerful, flexible, and downright handy [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) facility. (Not to be confused with the now-outmoded [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) interface.)

## Example Code

Here is example code based on the question.

```
public enum Liquid {
    COKE, PEPSI, JUICE, WATER
}
```

A method taking an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) of that enum type.

```
public Drink makeDrink ( EnumSet<Liquid> ingredients ) {
    System.out.println ( "ingredients: " + ingredients );
    if ( ingredients.contains ( Liquid.JUICE ) ) {
        // Treat as a Collection. 
        // `EnumSet` is just another `Set` implementation, though a very fast one.
    }
    for ( Liquid ingredient : ingredients ) {
        // Access each item in the collection, each Liquid object in the EnumSet.
    }
}
```

Code calling that method, instantiating and passing the necessary `EnumSet`.

```
EnumSet ingredients = EnumSet.of ( Liquid.COKE , Liquid.JUICE , Liquid.WATER );
Drink drink = this.makeDrink ( ingredients );
```

When run.

> ingredients: [COKE, JUICE, WATER]

Keep in mind these are real objects, type-safe, compiler-enforced, statically defined, and self-documenting. Do not mistake them for mere strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have also [Java EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), so you can get the value from the `EnumMap` of all the `USE_XXX` needed for your drink before pass the sums of them to your method

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple options to implement this.

- I personally like the C style way of bit manipulation just creating a enumeration or set of final statics.
- Another option in Java is to use the [java.util.BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) object.
- Probably the cleanest from a true OOP view would be to implement a utility class with boolean getter/setters.  That utility class would then be passed to the object that needs to use the flags.