# Enum Set JPA 2.0

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Please take a look at my former question to get the background.

[List of enum vs. class of booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766282/list-of-enum-vs-class-of-booleans)

However, my question is how enum sets are working with JPA 2.0 and databases. Since I would probably save the values as strings (cause I don't want risk to loose the mapping), a enumset of say > 20 enums in the set might be a very ineffective way to store data comparing with the bool class.

Consider a user table with different roles:

```
user | password | role (enum)
adm    1223       admin, guest, www, lab, elevator, ap, // Might be more than > 20
sam    0000       admin
```

.......

What should I choose? Do you have any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: This sounds like extreme premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above database design is not how you should store roles for a user. It is not normalized (since you have several values in a single column), and is thus very hard to query. How would you make a query to know all the users which have the roles `guest` or `ap`, for example?

Change the design to something like that:

```
user table : id, name, passord
role table: id, name
user_role join table: user_id, role_id
```

In JPA terms, you would simply have a `User` entity, a `Role` entity, and a `ManyToMany` association between those entities: a user has 0, 1 or several roles, and a role is held by 0, 1 or several users.

Comment: Thanks, I think I go for a class of booleans for a object with multiple selectors and enums for object with single selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to store the information in the binary form with relatively small size, I would go for `EnumSet` and if you would like to be able to query by types then I would pick `@ElementCollection`.